# What should be the dimension of app icon image asset Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

So when creating new image asset for the icon app on Android Studio what dimension should the .png that I upload to the image asset have? I mean what would be the perfect dimension of the png file,512x512 px?

Comment: Whatever size, Android studio will resize it to the required size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create app icon using mipmap -> Image Assets
use your 512x512 playstore icon you have already designed probably!

it will create app icons according to the possible screen sizes you just have to adjust the icon inside circle while creating it